# Add local file url to allowed domains Firefox : about:config

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on, getusermedia

I am creating a screen sharing addon in Firefox and need to use : **media.getusermedia.screensharing" feature.**
But since I am working locally using AddOn SDK, my url of opened html file is :  **resource://jid1-q3wuqdulcvnnrq-at-jetpack/toolbar_button/data/index.html**

Now, on this link I get an error :

```
 In about:config, please enable media.getusermedia.screensharing.enabled
and add this site's domain name to media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains in about:config
```

Also It requires an https connection.
While the same WebRTC works fine in Chrome extension.

Can someone please guide on how to add local file url to allowed domains? or to use getusermedia for local development.

Comment: Nice question and nice addon idea!

Comment: Someone on irc said that you can white list chrome url's, can you try that plz and let me know how it works

Answer (score 1):

A search on mxr for screensharing:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/search?string=screensharing

which led to this whitelist:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/dom/media/MediaManager.cpp#151

So then i checked domains already in this pref, they were: `webex.com,*.webex.com,collaborate.com,*.collaborate.com`

so when i did this: `Services.io.newURI('http://www.webex.com', null, null)` i got this:
[image]

So it looks like whatever is in `host` is what we want in this pref. So i tried newURI of file uri:

`Services.io.newURI('file:///C:/Users/Vayeate/Documents/GitHub/Profilist/bullet_aurora.png',null,null)`

it dumps this:
[image]

so im thinking in the the pref add this:
`,,`

which is a blank space, which is what it looks like it is for file uris
so mine would look like: `webex.com,*.webex.com,collaborate.com,,*.collaborate.com`

or can even trying just an asterik so like:

`webex.com,*.webex.com,collaborate.com,*.collaborate.com,*`

Comment: Giving permission denied.. Updated firefox about:config => media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains

Comment: if , , whitelisted file:// URIs, that would be a bug.  It's also possible to whitelist a (real) URI with an extension (talky.io has done this).  Whitelisting file: is dangerous...

Comment: Thanks @jesup what about whitelisting a specific file uri? Or maybe he should use chrome paths?

Comment: @Noitidart Sorry, no whitelisting of any file:/// URL.  Too dangerous.  browser-chrome code has other options, but I would be very careful with getUserMedia from addons, and in particular UI is problematic from browser-chrome.  Come to irc.mozilla.org and ask in #media

Comment: Thanks @jesup can you please share the browser-chrome options in a solution below. I'll get on irc to ask about the getUserMedia method. I'm curious about this now. Thanks

Comment: Hi @jesup may you please share that browser-chrome method, I am trying to do this from browser-chrome but am hitting the error `name: "SourceUnavailableError", message: "Failed to allocate videosource"`. I think I got around the permission error, but how come the videosource cant allocate. I am trying to simply let user taking webcam shot. And then hopefully add screen shot feature next.

Comment: @Noitidart -- Sorry for not noticing this earlier.  If you're still interested, come to #media on irc.mozilla.org, or ask on the mozilla dev-media mailing-list/newsgroup.   Florian (flo-retina on IRC) or jib may be able to help.  More context is needed that one can get in comments here

Comment: @jesup ok will catch you guys there. I made the addon but I used some undocumented and unexpected hack - its not uploading due to size of ffmpeg.js so am waiting for them to fix that bug - here is the addon - https://github.com/mozilla/addons/issues/145 - there is a dropbox link in there. I'll catch you guys on media when i can get some time to put the issues into succinct message. I had to do a lot of weird stuff haha